# Function to extract data frames from a list does not provide any output

Tags: r

I am not sure why my function is not working.  It loads into the environment, but it returns nothing when I use it.  I think the problem may be that I have not specified the "return" argument, but I am not sure where or how it should be placed?  Thank you for any help.

Here is the function that I want to use to extract data frames from a list, after I have used the split function to subset a larger data frame.

```
extractDF<- function(x) {
  dfname<-names(x)
  n<-length(x)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    nam <- dfname[i]
    assign (nam, data.frame(x[i]))
  }
}
```

When I use this loop outside of a function it works just as it should.  Here is the working loop...

```
dfname<-names(SubPop)
n<-length(dfname)
for (i in 1:n) {
  nam <- dfname[i]
  assign (nam, data.frame(SubPop[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `funtion` seems to `append` column names of different datasets in the list with `names` of the `list`.  If that is the case, use `envir=.GlobalEnv` in the `assign`

```
extractDF<- function(x) {
  dfname<-names(x)
  n<-length(x)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    nam <- dfname[i]
    assign (nam, data.frame(x[i]), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  }
}

extractDF(SubPop)
```

Now, check the `df1` and `df2`.  The `colnames` are changed.

```
colnames(df1)
#[1] "df1.Species8" "df1.Species4" "df1.Species1" "df1.Species5" "df1.Species7"
#[6] "df1.Species6"
colnames(df2)
#[1] "df2.Species4"  "df2.Species7"  "df2.Species5"  "df2.Species10"
#[5] "df2.Species1"  "df2.Species2"  "df2.Species6"  "df2.Species8"
```

#### Update

If you don't want to modify the `colnames` and assuming that the function was just to extract the modified datasets within in the list (from some other analysis), you can do:

```
list2env(setNames(SubPop, ls(pattern="^df\\d+")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Here, I am using `setNames` so as to name the `SubPop` list elements (in case it is unnamed).

#### data

```
set.seed(22)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 10*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=6,
  dimnames=list(NULL, sample(paste0("Species", 1:10), 6, replace=FALSE))))


set.seed(35)
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 10*8, replace=TRUE), ncol=8,
dimnames=list(NULL, sample(paste0("Species", 1:10),8 , replace=FALSE))))

SubPop <- list(df1, df2)
names(SubPop) <- c('df1', 'df2')
dfname<-names(SubPop)
```

Comment: Is there a simple edit to the function that would leave the column names unchanged? If it's tricky, don't worry, this is already doing exactly what I hoped it would.

Comment: @giderk I was a bit confused by your `title` and the `code`.  If you don't need to change the column names (assuming that you did some modifications of the dataframes within the `list`.  Use `list2env(setNames(SubPoP, ls(pattern="^df\\d+")), envir=.GlobalEnv)`